# Why is my code not returning a value for a future value payment?

Tags: javascript, html

Trying to create a Javascript for future value calculation.  This is the code im using but it is not returning a value.  Don't know where the code is wrong.  Has user input investment, interest rate, monthly payment added, and terms.  After that code how do I create a for loop to create an amortization schedule.

```
<body>
    <form name="fv">
        <table>
            <tr><td colspan="3"><b>Enter Investment Information:</b></td></tr>
            <tr>
                <td>1)</td>
                <td>Amount of the Investment (any currency):</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="investment" size="12"
                           onchange="calculate();">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>2)</td>
                <td>percentage rate of interest:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="interest" size="12"
                           onchange="calculate();">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>3)</td>
                <td>Monthly Payment Amount:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="monthly" size="12"
                           onchange="calculate();">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4)</td>
                <td>Terms:</td>
                <td>
                    <input type="text" name="terms" size="12"
                           onchange="calculate();">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate();">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td colspan="3">
                    <b>Investment Information:</b>
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td>4)</td>
                <td>Your Investment will be worth:</td>
                <td><input type="text" name="payment" size="12"></td>
            </tr>
        </table>
    </form>
    <script language="JavaScript">function calculate() {
            var investment = document.fv.investment.value;
            var interest = document.fv.interest.value / 100 / 12;
            var terms = document.fv.terms.value * 12;

            var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, terms);
            var monthly = (investment * x);

            if (!isNaN(monthly) &&
                (monthly != Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) &&
                (monthly != Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)) {

                document.fv.payment.value = round(monthly);
                
            }
            else {
                document.fv.payment.value = "";
            }
        }

        function round(x) {
            return Math.round(x * 100) / 100;
            </script>
```

Comment: I do see you are missing the end `}` for the round function.

Comment: Are there any error messages? Can you output values throughout your function to determine where it's failing?

Comment: @imvain2 that fixed it. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know what exactly you meant but it return value into input you haven't closed round func and wrong type on script

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Title</title>
</head>
<body>
<form name="fv">
    <table>
        <tr><td colspan="3"><b>Enter Investment Information:</b></td></tr>
        <tr>
            <td>1)</td>
            <td>Amount of the Investment (any currency):</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="investment" size="12"
                       onchange="calculate();">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>2)</td>
            <td>percentage rate of interest:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="interest" size="12"
                       onchange="calculate();">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>3)</td>
            <td>Monthly Payment Amount:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="monthly" size="12"
                       onchange="calculate();">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4)</td>
            <td>Terms:</td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="terms" size="12"
                       onchange="calculate();">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="calculate();">
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="3">
                <b>Investment Information:</b>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>4)</td>
            <td>Your Investment will be worth:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="payment" size="12"></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
  function calculate() {
      var investment = document.fv.investment.value;
      var interest = document.fv.interest.value / 100 / 12;
      var terms = document.fv.terms.value * 12;

      var x = Math.pow(1 + interest, terms);
      var monthly = (investment * x);
       
      if (!isNaN(monthly) && (monthly !== Number.POSITIVE_INFINITY) &&
              (monthly !== Number.NEGATIVE_INFINITY)) {
          document.fv.payment.value = round(monthly);
      }
      else {
          document.fv.payment.value = "";
      }
  }

  function round(x) {
      return Math.round(x * 100) / 100;
  }
</script>
</body>

</html>
```